# Shift Shift Global Search in WebStorm is not working

Tags: webstorm

Apparently the <kbd>Shift + Shift</kbd> Global Search in WebStorm is a short-cut I [***must***](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/06/10-webstorm-shortcuts-you-need-to-know/) know.

However this shortcut hardly ever works for me. Here is an example. I am just searching for *"delay(0000)"*

If I do a normal project search it will find this OK no problem.

Am I using Shift+Shift search properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Search everywhere** (`Shift`+`Shift`) allows searching for classes/symbols/files/actions/settings, but it's not intended to be used for searching text across files; you need using **Edit | Find | Find in path** for this. If you miss a possibility to search for arbitrary text using **Search everywhere**, please vote for [IDEA-126395](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126395)

Comment: I was under the impression that shift+shit was supposed to search everywhere and anything